# Optimize if condition javascript

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I am just a newbie in javascript,
this is how i am writing if condition in a javascript,

```
function setAccType(accType) {
    if (accType == "PLATINUM") {
        return "Platinum Customer";
    } else if (accType == "GOLD") {
        return "Gold Customer";
    } else if (accType == "SILVER") {
        return "Silver Customer";
    }
},
```

Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: The comma after function is not required

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use an object as a map:

```
function setAccType(accType){
  var map = {
    PLATINUM: 'Platinum Customer',
    GOLD: 'Gold Customer',
    SILVER: 'Silver Customer'
  }

  return map[accType];
}
```

---

Or as @Tushar pointed out:

```
var accountTypeMap = {
  PLATINUM: 'Platinum Customer',
  GOLD: 'Gold Customer',
  SILVER: 'Silver Customer'
}

function setAccType(accType){  
  return accountTypeMap[accType];
}
```

Comment: `map` can be moved outside of the function

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `accType` will always be passed to function.

1. Convert the string to first capital and other small case
2. Append *Customer* to it

Code:

```
return accType[0] + accType.slice(1).toLowerCase() + ' Customer';
```

Code Explanation:

1. `accType[0]`: Get the first character of the string
2. `accType.slice(1).toLowerCase()`: Get the string except first character

Answer (score 2):

```js
var TYPES = {
  "PLATINUM":"Platinum Customer",
  "GOLD":"Gold Customer",
  "SILVER":"Silver Customer"
}

function getType(acctType){
    return TYPES[acctType];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using the `switch` block if you are comparing the same variable against different values and having different things happen in different cases:

```
function setAccType(accType){
    switch(accType) {
        case "PLATINUM" :
            return "Platinum Customer";
        case "GOLD":
            return "Gold Customer";
        case "SILVER":
            return "Silver Customer";
     }
 }
```